# Google reCAPTCHA cannot be solved in Electron BrowserWindow

Tags: node.js, electron, recaptcha

In my Electron app I try to open an external website (e.g. `BrowserWindow.lodUrl('www.abc.xyz')`), which is protected by Googles reCAPATCHA. The browser Window with the page is open, so the user could solve the captcha and it does not act like a bot.

But somehow, the only response for the reCAPTCHA validation request is

```
)]}'
["rresp",null,null,null,null,null,1]
```

Also no reCAPTHCA popup for "street sign" or "crossign" selection appears.

Additionally I get a warning in the console

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. 
A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. 
You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem, by adding the user agent to every request separately.

```js
const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36';
newSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback: (beforeSendResponse) => void) => {
    details.requestHeaders['userAgent'] = userAgent;
    callback({cancel: false, requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders});
})
```

Comment: Does not solve the issue for me.